# RESTful way to design GET for a resource with many to one relation

Tags: api, rest

I'm designing a music media library that has a list of media resources.

GET /medias (all media resources)
GET /medias/1 (get one media resource)

But media also is tied to catalog with a catalog id inside the media resource

```
...
{
   id: 1
   name: <media name>
   catalogId: 5
},
{
   id: 2
   name: <media name>
   catalogId: 5
}
...
```

I want to design a RESTFul endpoint that allows to get a resource by resource id and get a list of resources by catalog id. To me that sounds like a filter so...

Again to get a single media resource by the media id

```
GET /medias/1
```

To get all media by catalog id

```
GET /medias?catalogId={5}
```

This is nice as it keeps the query within the domain of media but I'm trying to understand the tradeoffs with this approach. Are queries reserved for this type of "foreign" key behavior? Am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

> Are queries reserved for this type of "foreign" key behavior?

Not by REST.

REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers, it doesn't care how you design your resource model, and it doesn't care what the underlying implementation of a resource is.